# invalid_grant - type = password: user or admin has not consented to use the application

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-api-apps

I am getting a consent error when trying to obtain a token. Because of our application, we can't show an interactive dialog to give consent.

> "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the
>   application with ID <'my native client app id'>. Send an
>   interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

```
AuthenticationContext ctx = new AuthenticationContext(
string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}","mytenant.onmicrosoft.com"));
UserPasswordCredential cred = new UserPasswordCredential("login@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com", "Password");
var result = ctx.AcquireTokenAsync("my api uri", "my native client id", cred);
```

We are using the `grant_type=password` and `client_id` is a Native app id, and `resource` is the Web API app URI.

Permissions-wise, from the client app, a delegated permission has been given to  access the api app and have also tried setting `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow : true` in the manifest.

All applications have been created in the new preview Azure AD section of the new portal (portal.azure.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately if your application needs access to certain resources like the Graph API, you will need to prompt for consent at least one time.

Even if your app doesn't have an interactive login experience, you should be able to prompt this once to unblock your scenario in your tenant.

Use the following URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<AppID>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<RedirectURI>&resource=<ResourceURI>&prompt=admin_consent
```

You can see here we have just simply generated the login URL which would be generated as part of an interactive login experience. You will need to fill out your own specific data like Reply URL, App ID, Resource URI, etc...

Note that we added a final query string at the end where we are forcing a "consent" prompt. This should be done by an Administrator, who would be able to consent on behalf of the whole tenant. Once you have done that, the username/password flow should start working for you.

Also, as an additional note, implicit grant flow has nothing to do with consent.
Please read this section in the OAuth 2 spec:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2

You should only use this setting if you are creating a single-page application with something like JavaScript; Otherwise, there are significant security concerns with this setting on applications that should not have it.

Comment: What value should be used for the redirect URI?

Comment: If you are creating a Web Application, the Redirect URI should be the location where you would like the Authorization Code returned to your service. Otherwise, for Native Client apps, you can use the default reply url: `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I tried to use that URL, but I got hung up two ways.  Note I was following the step-by-step in this link:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/get-started-with-office-365-management-apis.

What resulted was that the urn you suggested caused Chrome to either end (as in, process killed) or to not display anything.  In IE, I got error about a missing component, but no details about name of component.

Switching to http://localhost causes a redirect to my machine, which has no web server.  The URN shows promise, but can't get past browser issues.

Comment: Are you using [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries)? For Native Client apps, ADAL should capture the access token for pretty much any redirect uri. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551153/how-can-i-authenticate-to-aad-and-call-the-graph-api-as-a-native-client-applicat) out as maybe a way to perform a sanity check with your app configuration.

Comment: Yes, using ADAL.  But right now, just trying to get consent using a browser.  I'll check out the link too - thanks.  One more thing.  Your URL works better than MS's.  If I take the resource id which microsoft suggests (which should be https://manage.office.com), use your URN for redirect, and keep the prompt option, I get a working page in Chrome.  However, clicking accept doesn't lead anywhere, except it does change the querystring/url, which gives me a session id and a ctx value.

Comment: Hi, On receiving the same error I want to present the user with Admin consent screen, Where can I get the User tenant Id to construct the Admin consent URL Dynamically?