# How can I authenticate to AAD and call the Graph API as a Native Client application with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to do some very quick tests on Azure Active Directory, and I need a tool which will allow me to quickly authenticate to AAD, and make calls to the AAD Graph API.

I have registered a Native Client application in my directory already, and I have set it up to have the appropriate permissions to call the AAD Graph API.

I want to take a look at my AAD Token, and the output from the Graph API after my call. How can I use PowerShell to quickly accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [>> See here for instructions on how to create a similar script for
>   emulating a Daemon Client
>   Application using the Client Credential Flow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553323/how-can-i-authenticate-to-aad-and-call-the-graph-api-as-a-daemon-application-wit)

PowerShell allows you to load .NET assemblies right into your command line. This means that you are able to load [ADAL (Azure Active Directory Authentication Libraries)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) and use it to really simplify the authentication experience. Once you have acquired a token from ADAL, then you can simply use the `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet to make calls to the AAD Graph API.

First you need to download and save the .NET dlls for ADAL. The download link can be found [on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.28.3).

*Note: We specifically use ADAL v2 here.*

> You can extract the contents of the .nupkg with a File Extractor like 7z, WinZip, etc...

Extract the contents from `\lib\net45\` and copy them into your working directory. I put the files in their own "ADAL" folder, to keep it separate.

Then you should be able to create a new PowerShell script with the following:

```
# Load ADAL
Add-Type -Path ".\ADAL\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"

# Output Token and Response from AAD Graph API
$accessToken = ".\Token.txt"
$output = ".\Output.json"

# Application and Tenant Configuration
$clientId = "<AppIDGUID>"
$tenantId = "<TenantID>"
$resourceId = "https://graph.windows.net"
$redirectUri = New-Object system.uri("<ReplyURL>")
$login = "https://login.microsoftonline.com"

# Get an Access Token with ADAL
$authContext = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext ("{0}/{1}" -f $login,$tenantId)
$authenticationResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceId, $clientID, $redirectUri) 
($token = $authenticationResult.AccessToken) | Out-File $accessToken

# Call the AAD Graph API
$headers = @{ 
    "Authorization" = ("Bearer {0}" -f $token);
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri ("{0}/{1}/users?api-version=1.6" -f $resourceId, $tenantId) -Headers $headers -OutFile $output
```

*Note: You will need to update the App ID, Tenant ID, and Reply URL in this script. I have also pre-configured the AAD Graph API call to return the users in my tenant, but you can change this REST call to whatever you want.*

After you successfully run the script, you should get 2 new files in your working directory: A text file that contains your encoded JSON access token, which can be base64 decoded on sites like [this](http://calebb.net/), and a JSON file with the response from the AAD Graph API.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I'm looking for a similar example but for ADAL V3, can anyone point me in the right direction?