# How can I authenticate to AAD and call the Graph API as a Daemon Application with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to do some very quick tests on Azure Active Directory, and I want to use a Daemon Application to access the Graph API without needing a user present to authenticate. I want to verify that my application registration can successfully authenticate to AAD, that my client secret is valid, and make calls to the AAD Graph API.

I have registered a "Web App/API" in my directory already, and I have set it up to have the appropriate permissions to call the AAD Graph API in the App Only Context. I have also generated an application key/certificate for my app so that I can authenticate as a confidential client.

I want to take a look at my AAD Token, and the output from the Graph API after my call. How can I use PowerShell to quickly accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I authenticate to AAD and call the Graph API as a Native Client application with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551153/how-can-i-authenticate-to-aad-and-call-the-graph-api-as-a-native-client-applicat)

Comment: These are effectively the same exact question and answer as each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551153/how-can-i-authenticate-to-aad-and-call-the-graph-api-as-a-native-client-applicat) where create a PowerShell script to authenticate as a Native Client Application. However, in this situation, there are some subtle and important differences because you want to authenticate as a confidential client. Specifically, we need to create a `Client Credential` so that we can authenticate without a user as a [Daemon Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api).

First you need to download and save the .NET dlls for ADAL. The download link can be found on Nuget.

*Note: We specifically use ADAL v2 here.*

> You can extract the contents of the .nupkg with a File Extractor like
>   7z, WinZip, etc...

Extract the contents from `\lib\net45\` and copy them into your working directory. I put the files in their own "ADAL" folder, to keep it separate.

Then you should be able to create a new PowerShell script with the following:

```
# Load ADAL
Add-Type -Path ".\ADAL\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"

# Output Token and Response from AAD Graph API
$accessToken = ".\Token.txt"
$output = ".\Output.json"

# Application and Tenant Configuration
$clientId = "<AppIDGUID>"
$tenantId = "<TenantID>"
$resourceId = "https://graph.windows.net"
$login = "https://login.microsoftonline.com"

# Create Client Credential Using App Key
$secret = "<AppKey>"


# Create Client Credential Using Certificate
#$certFile = "<PFXFilePath>"
#$certFilePassword = "<CertPassword>"
#$secret = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate -ArgumentList $certFile,$certFilePassword


# Get an Access Token with ADAL
$clientCredential = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential($clientId,$secret)
$authContext = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext("{0}/{1}" -f $login,$tenantId)
$authenticationResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceId, $clientcredential)
($token = $authenticationResult.AccessToken) | Out-File $accessToken


# Call the AAD Graph API 
$headers = @{ 
    "Authorization" = ("Bearer {0}" -f $token);
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri ("{0}/{1}/users?api-version=1.6" -f $resourceId,$tenantId)  -Headers $headers -OutFile $output
```

*Note: You will need to update the App ID, Tenant ID, and your App Secret information in this script. If you use a certificate to authenticate, simply comment out the code that uses the App Key, and un-comment the code which uses the certificate. I have also pre-configured the AAD Graph API call to return the users in my tenant, but you can change this REST call to whatever you want.*

After you successfully run the script, you should get 2 new files in your working directory: A text file that contains your encoded JSON access token, which can be base64 decoded on sites like [this](http://calebb.net/), and a JSON file with the response from the AAD Graph API.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Wouldn't it be way simpler to just `Invoke-RestMethod` to the token endpoint with the client id, secret and resource? No need for ADAL if using client credentials grant.

Comment: Yeah, this really is meant more for the certificate scenario, but it is so easy to wrap in the app key, I decided to include it as well.

Comment: @juunas Also, using `client_secret` usually leads to secrets lying around in plaintext in scripts, which tend to get (over) shared and are overall improperly managed. Using certificates has the overhead of needing to create a signed assertion (which ADAL does wonderfully easily), but eliminates secrets in the scripts themselves.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret Very true, you just have that overhead of generating the cert, adding it to the app in AAD, and installing it in the cert store on the machine.

Comment: @juunas Agree, there's an overhead in setting up and authorizing the client certificate in the first place as well. I have a simple helper function in my PowerShell profile that generates a short-lived (few days) cert and uses [`New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azuread/v2/new-azureadapplicationkeycredential) to authorize the certificate on the app in question.