# Azure RM: Logging in to CLI 1.0 using Azure AD application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I have a multi-tenant application in azure and was looking to find a way to login using Azure CLI. So far I have been unsuccessful.

The following command works well with service principal but fails with application

`azure login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <password> --tenant <tenant-id>`

Is it possible to use Azure AD application with Azure CLI?

Answer (score 0):

No , service principal is the identity for the app and could be used to authenticate the app with its own credentials. So if you have an app that needs to access resources , you need to create a service principal for an Active Directory application, and the service principal has permissions on your subscription, then you can use the azure login command to authenticate the service principal.

Comment: yes, Consider the application already has a service principal in the AD. I currently use the OAuth flow to access the resources. Is there nothing similar with respect to CLI or Powershell?

Comment: So you could authenticate to AAD and access resource with client credential flow (app identity) in powershell ,please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42553324/5751404)