# Active directory check if user belongs to a group

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am using the below code to pull active directory groups. How can I find out if a user belongs to xyz group or not?

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal 
GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of groups a user is a member of by querying the `memberOf` navigation property on the user object.

Read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsersMemberships).

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}/$links/memberOf?api-version
```

Note that you can remove the `$links` part of the query to return the whole group object, rather than the link to the object. However, for simply validating a user is a member of a certain group, you can use the links, and compare the object id of the groups that are returned to the one you are looking for.

Comment: very useful pointer. When I run this in browser it says authentication missing. any help on this please

Comment: Are you simply trying to go to that link? You need to make a REST call to GET the content from that API. You must have an access token already.

Comment: thanks for the info. sounds very interesting and helpful.

Comment: To get bootstrapped you can look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551153/how-can-i-authenticate-to-aad-and-call-the-graph-api-as-a-native-client-applicat/42551154#42551154). Or you can follow any one of our samples [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=graph&type=&language=).

Comment: This gives GUID names instead of group names. Any query to get group names or query by group name if a user belong to a group?

Comment: You can remove the `$links` part of the query to return the whole group. That response will contain group name.