# Get the access token in asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I want to get the access token to call some apis in my web form application , but I want to say that application already is a big project ,  and I don't want to use any library, I only want to click a button, enter name/password, and get access token , all I want to do is inside a page code , not anything other may affect the whole project , such as install a library .

Comment: :O buddy, please start learning about API and access token. you will understand. its not like one small job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done related code sample before in a web forms application , but you should firstly  understand how [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) works in AAD . After that , you could click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43537198/5751404) for code sample . And you will find in my code i use ADAL to get the access token using the authorization code . What you need to do is that modify the `AcquireTokenWithResource` function by :

1. prepare the request parameters and sending a POST request to the /token endpoint.
2. Deserialize the json result and get the access token . You could use Newtonsoft.Json library .

Any problem during coding , please feel free to let me know .

Comment: Your code is really helpful!!! I faced a redirect URL error,but finally make my project work!thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Getting an access token to Azure Active Directory on behalf of a user  only requires that you follow the Authorization Code Grant Flow.

While our libraries make this REALLY simple to accomplish ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551153/how-can-i-authenticate-to-aad-and-call-the-graph-api-as-a-native-client-applicat)), they are absolutely not required.

Learn about the OAuth 2 Protocol here: [Authorize access to web applications using OAuth 2.0 and Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code)

The short summary of the content is:

1. Register an AAD Application
2. Have a user login to your application using a specific login url which contains information about your application identity.

   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
   client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
   &response_type=code
   &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
   &response_mode=query
   &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
   &state=12345`
3. This will return an Authorization Code to the Redirect URI, which you will need to exchange for an access token:

   `POST /{tenant}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
   Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   grant_type=authorization_code
   &client_id=2d4d11a2-f814-46a7-890a-274a72a7309e
   &code=AwABAAAA...
   &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
   &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
   &client_secret=p@ssw0rd`
4. If you did everything successfully, you should now be in possession of an Access Token. Feel free to call your APIs now. :)