# How to call secured azure function from asp.net webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have written a simple Azure function.. To secure Azure function, I executed steps mentioned in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-microsoft).

Now from ASP.NET WebForms, I am trying to call my Azure Function API.
Following is the code. But I get "Unauthorized" exception. Can any help me. 
I understand that somehow I have to provide authorization token while calling api URL, but I don't know how to get token and how to send it along with the url call. Can someone help me please.

```
public void SecureAzureCalls()
{
    string url = @"https://afxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/afcodes";

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = true
    };

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));

    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Go thru the answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43717038/get-the-access-token-in-asp-net-web-forms) question.

Comment: This code wouldn't even compile, so you shouldn't be getting an Unauthorized exception. Your method isn't marked as `async`, so you can't use `await`. And if you're going to use async, you can't (well, really shouldn't!) have a void return type. You need to return a Task or Task<T>