# Azure AD - Oauth2 returning Invalid Authentication Token

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory

Hi I am very new to azure ad and trying to use GraphAPI using Oauth2.

I currently have my code:

```
static let tenant = "tenant.com"
static let clientId = "22d31baa-5acf-4324-8ac1-02f0021g4f56"
static let redirectURI = URL.init(string: "test://com.test.est")
static let authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/\(tenant)/oauth2/authorize"
static let resourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com"


var authContext: ADAuthenticationContext!

func getAuth(){
    var error: ADAuthenticationError? = nil
    authContext = ADAuthenticationContext(authority: Authentication.authority, error: &error)
    authContext.acquireToken(withResource: Authentication.resourceId, clientId: Authentication.clientId, redirectUri: Authentication.redirectURI, completionBlock: {(result:ADAuthenticationResult!) in
        if(result.accessToken == nil){
            //Token acquisition failed
            print("Failed receving Token")
        }else{
            //Toekn acquisition succeeded
            let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(result.tokenCacheStoreItem.accessToken)"]

            Alamofire.request("\(Authentication.resourceId)/me", headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                print(response)
            })

        }
    })
}
```

When this code is executed i get, result:

```
SUCCESS: {
error =     {
    code = InvalidAuthenticationToken;
    innerError =         {
        date = "2017-05-05T22:44:39";
        "request-id" = "22d31baa-5acf-4324-8ac1-02f0021g4f56";
    };
    message = "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184105";
};
```

}

The error message is printed inside alamofire.request.
I feel like my authority is messed up because when I erase oauth2 portion, it still returns the same result. I try studying oauth2 again but let me know if any mistake going on in my code.
Thanks a lot

Comment: What kind of token are you trying to get? An [App Only Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) or a [Delegated Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code)? I ask because your authority says you want to get an Authorization Code, but your getAuth() function does not seem to go through the process of getting an Authorization Code.

Comment: Ah sorry. Please ignore the function name. I am still new to Azure and was testing multiple things in the function.

Comment: What i want to achieve is to get token and use the token and access the Graphapi.... Still struggling.

Comment: Have you looked at any of our [End to End samples](https://github.com/azure-samples)? Have you tried running through the simple "hello world" of [graph tokens with PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551153/how-can-i-authenticate-to-aad-and-call-the-graph-api-as-a-native-client-applicat)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out how to manage it.

```
import Foundation
import ADALiOS
import Alamofire


class Authentication{
let tenant: String
let clientId: String
let redirectURI: URL
let authority: String
let resourceId: String

init(){
    tenant = "tenant"
    clientId = "client"
    redirectURI = URL.init(string: "uri")!
    authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/\(tenant)/authorize?client_id=\(clientId)&response_type=code&redirect_uri=\(redirectURI)&response_mode=query"
    resourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
}

private var authContext: ADAuthenticationContext!

private var token: String? = nil
var response: DataResponse<Any>? = nil


func authorize(){

    var error: ADAuthenticationError? = nil
    authContext = ADAuthenticationContext(authority: authority, error: &error)
    authContext.acquireToken(withResource: resourceId, clientId: clientId, redirectUri: redirectURI, completionBlock: {(result:ADAuthenticationResult!) in
        if(result.accessToken == nil){
            //Token acquisition failed
            print("Failed receving Authorizing Token")
        }else{
            //Token acquisition succeeded
            let headers = [
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
                "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
                "Authorization":"Bearer \(result.tokenCacheStoreItem.accessToken!)"
            ]
            Alamofire.request("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/", headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                self.response = response
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Basically, I had to add some headers and use beta. If i use other than beta, it returns invalid version error.