# ADAL.js - acquire token for Graph API resources

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, adal.js

I'm developing a SPA app in React that needs to integrate with AzureAD and the GraphAPI (implicit flow).

My question is very similar to: [ADAL.js - Obtaining Microsoft Graph Access Token with id_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802838/adal-js-obtaining-microsoft-graph-access-token-with-id-token) ... but the answer doesn't show me enough code to get me on my way.

So far, using just adal.js (v1.0.14), I can login & get an id_token, but I can't figure out how to use it to get access to make Graph API calls.

UPDATE: I know I'm correctly registered with the Azure portal, because I was able to login and get recent docs without adal.js or any lib ... just using home-made ajax calls.

Here's my code, which does the login/redirect, and then tries to get my recent docs:

```
// Initial setup      
var adalCfg = {
  instance              : 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
  tenant                : 'common',
  clientId              : 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  postLogoutRedirectUri : window.location.origin,
  extraQueryParameter   : 'scope=Mail.ReadWrite+Files.Read+Files.ReadWrite+User.ReadBasic.All' // Is this the proper way to specify what resources I need access to?
};

var authContext = new Adal(adalCfg);

if(!authContext.getCachedUser()) {
  authContext.login();  // redirects MS login page successfully
}

// Check For & Handle Redirect From AAD After Login
var isCallback = authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash); // Checks if the URL fragment contains access token, id token or error_description.
if(isCallback) {
  authContext.handleWindowCallback(); // extracts the hash, processes the token or error, saves it in the cache and calls the registered callbacks with the result.
}

if (isCallback && !authContext.getLoginError()) {
  window.location = authContext._getItem(authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST); // redirects back to /
}

// Try to get my recent docs - FAILS with InvalidAuthenticationToken error
// UDPATED authContext.acquireToken(authContext.config.clientId, function (error, token) {
authContext.acquireToken('https://graph.microsoft.com', function (error, token) {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent',
    headers:{'authorization':'Bearer '+ token},
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'json'
  }).done(function(res) {
    console.log(res['value']);
  });

});
```

What have I got wrong?

---

Update 2: I changed `acquireToken` per Fei's answer, but now when adal silently gets an access token for my resource, it fails to pass it to my API call.

Updated code:

```
    adalCfg.endpoints.graphApiUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

    authContext.acquireToken(adalCfg.endpoints.graphApiUri, function (errorDesc, token, error) {
      console.log('errorDesc = ' + errorDesc)
      console.log('token = ' + token)      
      console.log('error = ' + error)

      $.ajax({
        url: adalCfg.endpoints.graphApiUri + '/v1.0/me/drive/recent',
        headers:{'authorization':'Bearer '+ token},
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json'
      }).done(function(res) {
        console.log(res['value']);
      });

    });
```

And console output:

[Token not being captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMcdI.png)

The image shows the req for a token, which appears to succeed, because the next GET contains the `access_token` in the hash. However, `acquireToken` passes a `null` token to my Graph API call.

However, if I manually grab the access token out of the hash, I can successfully make the Graph API call.

Why doesn't adal pass the access token to my API call? It came back and is valid.

Comment: Is it helpful to and the endpoints to the config like `https://graph.windows.net`. I also update the post to add a code sample which calling the Microsoft Graph. If you still have the issue, you may share a runable code sample to help reproducing this issue.

Comment: Is the issue fixed? If not, please check the code sample I update to see whether it is helpful. And if you still have the problem, you can share a runable code sample to help us to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Back to this - @FeiXue-MSFT , yes your code sample works for me. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call the Microsoft Graph, we need to get the specific token for this resource. Based on the code you were acquire the token using the `authContext.config.clientId`.

If you register the app on Azure portal, to get the access token for the Microsoft Graph, you need to replace `authContext.config.clientId` with `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

And to call the REST sucessfully, we need to make sure having the enough permission. For example, to list recent files, one of the following scopes is required:`Files.Read`,`Files.ReadWrite`,`Files.Read.All`,`Files.ReadWrite.All`,`Sites.Read.All`,`Sites.ReadWrite.All`(refer [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_recent)).

### Update

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules\adal-angular\lib\adal.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="login"> login</button>
<button id="clickMe">click me</button>
<script>


$(function () {
    var endpoints = {
          "https://graph.microsoft.com": "https://graph.microsoft.com"
    };
    window.config = {
        tenant: 'xxxx.onmicrosoft.com',
        clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        endpoints: endpoints
    };
    window.authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);


    $("#login").click(function () {
        window.authContext.login();
    });

    $("#clickMe").click(function () {
        var user = window.authContext.getCachedUser();
        console.log(user);

        window.authContext.acquireToken('https://graph.microsoft.com', function (error, token) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(token);

             $.ajax({
        url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/',
        headers:{'authorization':'Bearer '+ token},
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json'
      }).done(function(res) {
        console.log(res['userPrincipalName']);
      });

    });
        }
            );

    function init(){
        if(window.location.hash!="")
            window.authContext.handleWindowCallback(window.location.hash);
    }

    init();
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do I get ClientID?  We have an App registered in Azure AD with Graph API Rights. I want host this code on a web server outside of Azure (unrelated to the registered app) and don't want to register it.  Also, how can or should I use App Secret and Reply URLs of the registered app?

Comment: Hi got a second?

Comment: I am facing similar issue I can login using adal but when i pass the token in headers just like mentioned above its returning following response
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token validation failure.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "2600e8e9-27ea-488a-a5ab-cae0d4200e7c",
            "date": "2018-06-29T11:30:00"
        }
    }
}

Comment: I am using adal.js in my project and when i am calling graph api, I am getting logged out when I am passing 'https://graph.microsoft.com' instead of client id