# Web API on-behalf-of adal id_token error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, adal

I have created a Web API in Azure.
This Web API makes some calls in SharePoint Online. Some of the api calls are on-behalf-of.

This Web API works fine until 01.05.2018 - and it works fine on old app services, which were created before 01.05.2018.

A microsoft staff member said:

> As part of our security hardening efforts we do not allow id_token
>   redemption for any application created after 2018-05-01 00:00:00.

During the log in process of adal, I got the id_token. The id_token has got the same value as the access_token:
[image]

When I call the web api, I will send this token as bearer token.
The Web API takes this token (string accessToken) and starts the method 'AcquireTokenAsync':

```
        var clientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"];
        var clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
        var tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

        var appCred = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant);

        var resource = new Uri(sharePointUrl).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, appCred,
            new UserAssertion(accessToken));
        return authResult.AccessToken;
```

But in the line which calls 'AcquireTokenAsync' I have got the error message:

```
AADSTS240002: Input id_token cannot be used as 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer' grant
```

But where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use the same application identity in the front-end and back-end, and MS does not allow you to use the Id token (which you use as an access token here because of the former) to get another access token.

A possible solution:

- Register another application (the front-end JS app should be a Native app)
- It should acquire an access token for your back-end API using either the API's client id or app Id URI as the resource
- Then the API can exchange the access token for another access token

If this is a multi-tenant app, the migration is probably not going to be easy.
If it's single-tenant, then all should be possible.
Your front-end app should of course require permission to call your back-end API in Azure AD, and that permission should be granted.

Another solution would be to acquire the other access token in the front-end using ADAL.JS instead of using on-behalf-of in the back-end and attaching that to all API requests in addition to the Id token.

Comment: This is a single-tenant. The second solution seems to me comfortable. But how is it possible to get the other access token?

Comment: Good :) Then re-factoring these is possible and your admin can click Grant permissions to do admin consent on the app so your users never see a difference.

Comment: Though existing logins may fail after the update.. It might be a good idea to keep the current app as the front-end and add a new back-end app, that makes it the most painless for users at least.

Comment: From my point of view, I used ADAL.JS to get the id_token. But how can I get the other access token as you mentioned in your second solution?

Comment: This one might help for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44842719/1658906

Comment: the first solution could be possible too... but I do not know how to use front-end and back-end app... and if this works for my scenario

Comment: When I use this token, I have got the error message: AADSTS50013: Assertion contains an invalid signature.

Comment: I solved the problem...Mea culpa! As you mentioned the link to do two calls solved my issue. At first I used the graph.microsoft.com as resource, which is totally wrong in my case. I have to use tenantname.sharepoint.com. I will post my solution as a separated answer. But hugh thanks to @juunas!

Comment: @NickDelefski any update on the solution? We're dealing with a similar problem at work. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderTsepkov: Do you use SharePoint Online as your resource? Can you please post your error code.

Comment: @AlexanderTsepkov do you need any help anymore?